# How to hide the command line in IntelliJ IDEA console output?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to intellij IDE and trying to execute a class file and i have following issue when i execute java class file in intellij

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56791:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\satis\Desktop\Automation Framework\KarateSeries\target\classes" HelloWorld

Hellow World
```

How to get rid of the locations in my intellij output

Comment: You mean you want to get rid of the first line of the output?

Answer (score 5):

Add `java.exe` at File | Settings | Editor | General | Console, **Fold console lines that contain**.

IDE will collapse the command line and it will be less distracting.

It's not possible to hide it completely at the moment, you can vote for the related feature request:

- [IDEA-188173](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188173) A new option to turn off viewing folded code in Console

Comment: This is not an issue. I was thinking that I miss configured the setting that is causing all unnecessary output .

Comment: This behavior is currently by design, nothing to worry about.