# Can I exclude build output when running a Gradle project from IntelliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle project being run from the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA (2021.1.1 Ultimate Edition).  The project has a Java class with a main method that outputs its results to the console.

When I run this main method from IntelliJ IDEA, outputs the results of the program in the "Run" tab.  However, it also outputs the Gradle build output as well.  This is not desirable to me, since it makes the program output harder to visually distinguish, plus I have to carefully select just the program output, and can't just copy/paste the full output (click, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, click, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>).

**build.gradle**

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
```

**Main.java**

```java
package com.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program output line 1");
        System.out.println("Program output line 2");
        System.out.println("Program output line 3");
    }
}
```

**output**

```
1:20:08 PM: Executing task 'Main.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes

> Task :Main.main()
Program output line 1
Program output line 2
Program output line 3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 508ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
1:20:09 PM: Task execution finished 'Main.main()'.
```

---

### Aside

Similar behavior occurs if I switch the project settings to build and run using IntelliJ IDEA rather than Gradle, in that it outputs the Java command and a "process finished" message.  Even if I wanted to switch to running in this manner (which I don't for this project), I still run into a variant of this issue.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=61588:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/Example/GradleMainOutput/out/production/classes com.example.Main
Program output line 1
Program output line 2
Program output line 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

That all being said, is there a way to output only the program output in an IntelliJ IDEA Gradle project, and not the build output?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to hide Gradle build output when running in this mode.

The only way is to disable Gradle run delegation so that app is started directly by IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: no delegation]

Hiding the command line and the exit code is also [not possible](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259009).

You can only [fold it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987989/104891).

Comment: Just finished modifying my question to clarify that this doesn't quite work either.

Comment: I'd rather run this particular project using Gradle and not IntelliJ IDEA.  I mentioned this in my initial version of the question ("I know I could change the project settings to build and run using IntelliJ IDEA rather than with Gradle, but for various reasons I would prefer this to be built with Gradle."), and I've indicated the same in my expanded version.  Thanks, though.

Comment: for pure java project, works fine.

Comment: To expand upon my previous point, doing it this way displays the `[...] bin/java [...]` line and the `Process finished with exit code 0` line, so it has effectively the same problem as the Gradle approach — additional text present in the console beyond just the program output.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but for anybody still interested to just get the output of the script, you can use the --quiet flag (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html)

So having this in the `build.gradle` :

```
task(run, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.multimodule.module.MainClass'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

and execturing the task:

```
./gradlew multimodule:module:run --quiet
```

you'll get just the output (.e.g any System.out.println you added on the main)

Comment: This a helpful tip for the Gradle command line, though I'm not sure whether or how it can be adapted to the IntelliJ IDEA question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in IntelliJ *without* hacks. Open up your run configurations dialog:

[image]

Choose "Edit configuration templates" from the bottom left:

[image]

Modify the default Gradle run configuration with flags `--console-plain --quiet`:

[image]

Important! After you press OK, you must delete any existing run configs you have, because this change does not alter existing run configs:

[image]

Another important note! Do not press "Re-run" if you have an existing run/debug/test:

[image]

If you press that Re-run button, it will run with the old configuration. So, make sure you start a new run/debug/test:

[image]

And you're done!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `--console=plain` instead of `--console-plain`?

Comment: This almost gets me there.  I've confirmed that this removes all the Gradle text.  However, the IDEA starting and ending text is still printing: `1:20:08 PM: Executing task 'Main.main()'...` `5:59:49 PM: Execution finished 'run --console=plain --quiet'.`

Answer (score 0):

The `--quiet` flag helps, but it is not enough. For me the following flags combination works:

```bash
gradle --console-plain --quiet ...
```

Comment: This a helpful tip for the Gradle command line, though I'm not sure whether or how it can be adapted to the IntelliJ IDEA question being asked.

Comment: I posted an answer for IntelliJ not just console.