# Jetbrains Intellij Idea Encoding/Compiler Error (Regardless of Encoding style)/Intellij Idea Program Files Folder is Empty?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, program-files

I'm having issues with Intellij, when I'm running my code I get an error
I don't care that I'm copy/pasting my full filepath with name. Secret Message is the program I'm working on. When I use UTF-8 encoding, the same error occurs, just with UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Users\forel\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition\lib\idea_rt.jar=55495:C:\Users\forel\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition\bin" -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -classpath "C:\Users\forel\IdeaProjects\Secret Message\out\production\Secret Message" SecretMessage
```

EDIT: My Jetbrains Program Files Folder is empty????

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SecretMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str = scn.nextLine();

        String newStr = encode(str);

        System.out.println(newStr);
    }

    public static String encode(String str) {

        String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String enc = "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe";

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {

            str = str.toLowerCase();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length() - 1; j++) {
                if (letters.charAt(i) == enc.charAt(j)) {
                    str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), enc.charAt(j));
                }
            }
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any actual errors with the code. I'm inputting a string, creating a cipher, looping through the cipher, and converting the string to the new result. Then attempting to print it to console. If I did have any issues with how I'm looping through the cipher, I can figure it out on my own. What I NEED is to figure out what this weird issue is.

Comment: Is your question about why the line starting `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe"` is printed in the Run panel? This isn't an error, this is only IntelliJ printing the command that it's running. It's totally normal and doesn't indicate anything wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987989/29470

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.